# File not found packages.config

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have been getting this error recently on a project.

Copying file packages.config to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages.config failed. Could not find file 'packages.config'.

I am not using NuGet at all for this project, however this error occurred after a merging of changes from the trunk to my project branch, possibly bringing in changes from VS10. I'd like to simply remove the references to this packages.config or at least put in a dummy file to make the error go away. Any suggestions would help at this point.

Comment: Are you using the git repository with other developers?

Comment: We are using SVN to collaborate, I am working on a longer time frame feature, hence the branch. There does not appear to be any reference to NuGet or the packages.config in my vbproj file.

Comment: It is possible that someone else committed the csproj file with that file being included but didn't commit the actual file itself.

Comment: It turns out my co-worker was experimenting with a package, the problem was solved when she uninstalled that package and recommitted. Going forward we will have to be careful to make sure the packages.config is included in SVN.

Answer (score 1):

In your *.csproj file, try removing the line:

```
<None Include="packages.config" />
```

Remove any "Import" elements which match ".targets", and contain either "nuget" or "packages". They may be one or other dependening on NuGet version used to add packages.

Remove any "Target" elements and it's children if they contain "NuGet". Was added in a recent version to make it easier to restore missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using nuget, open your project file (*.csproj), find the line that looks like this:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

And delete it. This should get rid of nuget references.

*NB: in VS2010 this line might look different, but reference to `nuget.targets` should be present.*

Comment: I'm using nuget, there are no nuget.targets present in the project file. But instead build event target that will drop an error if the imported library is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it by looking at the 'source control' output (Menu->View->Output) and added the missing .nuget\packages.config folder+file.

Than committed it to TFS.

Than, I've removed the newly created folder+file and recommitted to TFS.

HTH.